# Modal Dialog sometimes does not gets called up using ajax in mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am displaying modal dialog using ajax, and using paging. I have found that when initial page is loaded then modal dialog gets called which is a partial view with Ajax, but if i click on next page and new DOM elements gets added then sometimes when i click on the Action link only a simple partial view is loaded without AJAX,it is not loaded within modal dialog when i debug it, suppose the id of  record i want to view is 11 then through ajax it is 11?==138445555 but when normal partial view is called it is Simply ViewDetail?page=3. I am using the following jquery code to call modal dialog.Please suggest where is the issue. Thanks....

```
$(function () {
    $.ajaxSetup({
        cache: false
    });
    $('.btnShowDialog').click(function () {
        $('.ShowModalDialog').load(this.href,function () {
            $('#ShowModal').modal({
                backdrop: 'static',
                Keyboard: true
            }, 'show');
        }),
        return false;
        e.preventDefault();
    }););
```

Comment: missing `}` at last `});`

Comment: Only that is the issue or somewhere else i am wrong because it is working perfectly when i am on the first page that is initially loaded.

Answer (score 0):

user2802591,

If you are changing some of the DOM elements, you may be changing the button in some way. I don't know for sure because I don't see all of the code.

Anyways, if this is true, jQuery's `click` method can't execute on dynamic DOM elements. Use this block instead:

```
$(document).on('click', '.btnShowDialog', function () {
     // code here
});
```

This will execute the function on the dynamic DOM element. Of course, this would be the solution if you are updating that button, or it is being changed in some way when you dynamically add elements.

Comment: I am loading the next page using ajax, and there the click event on a link is not called. thanks for your answer....

Answer (score 0):

1. u missed a "}"
2. prevent default should be in the start
3. with a new DOM you need to reset the click, or use "on" (live if u have an old JQ : http://api.jquery.com/on/)

> ```
> $(function () {
>     $.ajaxSetup({
>         cache: false
>     });
>     $('.btnShowDialog').on('click',function (e) {
>        e.preventDefault();
>
>         $('.ShowModalDialog').load(this.href,function () {
>             $('#ShowModal').modal({
>                 backdrop: 'static',
>                 Keyboard: true
>             }, 'show');
>         }),
>         return false;
>
>     });
> });
> ```

Comment: e is undeclared and needs to be passed in from the function callback